# problem add to cart not working in mozila

Tags: virtuemart

add to cart doesnt working in mozila firefox.only one time working when i refresh a page then when i am not refreshing the page it s not working add to cart option not display.

Comment: Without seeing any source code, it is really difficult to tell you where the problem is

Comment: It may be and it may be not; but it surely uses javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Disable cache on the server and see if it works. If it does, try disabling cache to some specific file cached by Firefox. Firebug helps too :/

Answer (score 1):

Probably, some Javascript error. Use Furebug and enable Stop on all errors on Script tab. It will then stop execution on all page script errors.

Answer (score 1):

JUst goto the component-> Virtuemart->configuration->Site tab->Select the theme for your Shop(default) ,clck on configuration then Use Ajax to add, update or delete products from the cart? option  makes it NO.
Like:
Use Ajax to add, update or delete products from the cart?     No
It will Work.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a jquery conflict. please check if your code loads multiple instances of jquery and let only one just after `<head>`.